# How to join an existing table that has starting date and closing date to the existing calendar table to calculate working days

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, sql-server-2005

How to join an existing table that has starting date and closing date to the existing calendar table to calculate working days .

My calendar table looks like this :-

```
dt  isweekday   isholiday   Y   FY  Q   M   D   DW  monthname   dayname W
1/1/2010 0:00   FALSE   FALSE   2010    2010    1   1   1   6   January Friday  1
1/2/2010 0:00   FALSE   FALSE   2010    2010    1   1   2   7   January Saturday    1
1/3/2010 0:00   TRUE    FALSE   2010    2010    1   1   3   1   January Sunday  2
1/4/2010 0:00   TRUE    FALSE   2010    2010    1   1   4   2   January Monday  2
1/5/2010 0:00   TRUE    FALSE   2010    2010    1   1   5   3   January Tuesday 2
1/6/2010 0:00   TRUE    FALSE   2010    2010    1   1   6   4   January Wednesday   2
```

and the other table containing start date and end date looks like the following :-

```
orderid orderdate   ordercloseddate actionby
40978   4/15/2010 12:47 4/18/2010 14:47 tjjohn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the working dates for a particular order.

```
SELECT dt FROM calendar CROSS JOIN orders
 where DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, dt), 0) between DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, orderdate), 0) and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, ordercloseddate), 0)
   AND isweekday = 'TRUE'
   AND isholiday = 'FALSE'
   AND orderid = <anOrderId>
```

For all orders,

```
 SELECT orderid, count(dt) AS workingDays FROM calendar CROSS JOIN orders
 where DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, dt), 0) between DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, orderdate), 0) and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, ordercloseddate), 0) 
   AND isweekday = 'TRUE'
   AND isholiday = 'FALSE'
 GROUP BY orderid
```

Comment: Thanks dear but its not working it says  ... Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: Thanks .. finally got it working .. i was using sql 2005 thus could not use the date thing  , simply removed it and it worked ... :) Thanks .

Comment: Worked Amazing >> Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select
  orderid,
  count(*)
from
  orders o
  join calendar c 
    on c.dt >= convert(date, c.orderdate) and
       c.dt <= convert(date, c.ordercloseddate) and
       c.isweekday = 'TRUE' and
       c.isholiday = 'FALSE'
group by
  o.orderid
```

Not sure about your 'isholiday' field, hopefully it's not a string with words TRUE / FALSE.

Comment: i am using sql 2005 and its giving this error Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: Date is only available from 2008 onwards, in 2005 you can use dateadd(DAY, datediff(DAY, 0, c.orderdate), 0)